# Set <tr> color on change of angular array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table

I am using angularJS. I've got  this code in my view layout:

```
<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <td>{{ car.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ car.speed }}</td>
    <td>{{ car.length }}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

At some point my angular-controller changes one of `$scope.cars` object.
**The point is:** I want to change a color of `<tr>` in which changed `car` stays when that happens.
**The question is:** How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flag it as changed.

Set `car.changed` to true when you've changed it

```
$scope.car[0].changed = true;
```

And conditionally apply the  `changedClass` with a background-color.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-class="{'changedClass': car.changed}">
        <td>{{ car.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ car.speed }}</td>
        <td>{{ car.length }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have seen issues on tr's with ng-class JAHU.